# How to get docs after filtering 2 arrays in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two types of semester first one is toEligible and other is toAll. Both types have lesson array where multiple lessons were inserted.  I wants to make a logic that when server receives record fetching request. Here, it check if semester is of type toEligible then it performs some conditions before sending data to client side.

**Conditions are.**

After checking semester type.
For new user/student it only sends first 2 lessons from very first toEligibel type semester ( may be there are multiple toEligible type semester's ). So, i have made a logic when this user takes a test and if he passed test i push that lesson id in **Plesson** array in **User Schema** . When user logins next time , server matches **Plesson** elements and lessons of very first toEligible type semester and sends passed lesson's with next 2 more lessons.

This is record fetching request

```
server.get('/load-record', (req, res, next) => {
    Record.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'semesters', populate: {
                path: 'lessons',
                options: {
                    // limit: 2
                }
            }
        })
        .populate({ path: 'events' })
        .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data[0].semesters)
            res.send({ status: true, loadedData: data })
        })
})
```

This is User Schema

```
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   username: { type: String, required: true },
   city: { type: String, required: true },
   password: { type: String, required: true },
   status: { type: String, required: true },
   imagePath: { type: String },
   date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   lastLoggedAt: { type: Date },
   Jlesson: [{
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: 'JLesson'
    }],
   Plesson: [{ type: Object }] 
    })
```